# Cannot open source file, additional directory changed

Tags: c++, linq

I am using Visual Studio 2015, and am trying to include codes from open source project, [Linq](https://github.com/pfultz2/Linq). I organized my files as follows:

- Linq ( open sources code folder )

  - linq.h
  - linq ( folder containing implementing codes )
- LinqVS ( my visual studio project folder )

  - main.cpp

'Linq' and 'LinqVS' are under the same folder. Then in the main.cpp file, I typed `#include <linq.h>`, then I got the error "cannot open source file".

Here is the thing that I have tried:

1. Add the directory for `Linq` into 'include directory' and/or 'additional include directory'. Doesn't work. ( I can see that the directory is correctly specified because it is reflected in the command line )
2. Copy & paste the 'linq.h' and 'linq folder' to `$VC_IncludePath`, it works. the code can be opened now. However, this means modifying other code folders. I want to avoid this.

So the question is, is there a way to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the project include directories. It is pretty simple.

As explained in [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855621.aspx)

1. To specify or modify directory settings In Solution Explorer, open
   the shortcut menu for the project you want to change and then choose
   Properties.
2. in the left pane of the Property Pages dialog box,
   expand Configuration Properties and then select VC++ Directories.
3. To modify one of the directory lists, select it, choose the down-arrow
   button on the right, and then choose Edit.
4. In the box in the dialog box that appears, you can add or remove values, and you can rearrange the order in which the values appear. You can also change whether the project inherits any settings by selecting or clearing Inherit from parent or project defaults.

In my experience you can then choose the needed folder. There shouldn't be any errors anymore.

Comment: I have tried this method by changing 'include directory' and 'additional include directory', it is not working i am afraid.